# reuse function with multiple string values pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm hoping to streamline a function that only return columns based on a single string value. Using below, I have two distinct colours in a df. I want to pass each colour to a function. But I only want the output to include columns relating to that colour.

If I have numerous colours and multiple outputs within the function, the returned df gets too large.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = ({
    'Date' : ['1/1/18','1/1/18','2/1/18','3/1/18','1/2/18','1/3/18','2/1/19','3/1/19'],                 
    'Val' : ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D'],   
    'Blue' : ['Blue', 'Blue', 'Blue', np.NaN, np.NaN, 'Blue', np.NaN, np.NaN],   
    'Red' : [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 'Red', 'Red', np.NaN, 'Red', 'Red']                                 
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%d/%m/%y')

df['Count'] = df.Date.map(df.groupby('Date').size())


def func(df, val):
    
    df['%s_cat' % val] = df['Count'] * 2

    return df


blue = func(df, 'Blue')


red = func(df, 'Red')
```

Intended output (Blue):

```
        Date Val  Blue   Count  Blue_cat 
0 2018-01-01   A  Blue       2         4        
1 2018-01-01   B  Blue       2         4        
2 2018-01-02   C  Blue       1         2               
5 2018-03-01   B  Blue       1         2
```

Intended output (Red):

```
        Date Val  Blue  Red  Count   Red_cat
3 2018-01-03   D   NaN  Red      1         2
4 2018-02-01   A   NaN  Red      1         2
6 2019-01-02   C   NaN  Red      1         2
7 2019-01-03   D   NaN  Red      1         2
```

Comment: I think you just forgot to indent your return statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) for avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`, because if you modify values in filtered DataFrame later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data, and that Pandas does warning:

```
def func(df, val):
    df = df[df[val].eq(val)].copy()
    df[f'{val}_cat'] = df['Count'] * 2

    return df

blue = func(df, 'Blue')
print (blue)
        Date Val  Blue  Red  Count  Blue_cat
0 2018-01-01   A  Blue  NaN      2         4
1 2018-01-01   B  Blue  NaN      2         4
2 2018-01-02   C  Blue  NaN      1         2
5 2018-03-01   B  Blue  NaN      1         2

red = func(df, 'Red')
print (red)
        Date Val Blue  Red  Count  Red_cat
3 2018-01-03   D  NaN  Red      1        2
4 2018-02-01   A  NaN  Red      1        2
6 2019-01-02   C  NaN  Red      1        2
7 2019-01-03   D  NaN  Red      1        2
```